# pyspark AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cast'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is wrong with my code, I am using pyspark to convert a data type of a column.

```
company_df=company_df.withColumn("Revenue" ,company_df("Revenue").cast(DoubleType()))  \
                    .withColumn("GROSS_PROFIT",company_df("GROSS_PROFIT").cast(DoubleType()))    \
                    .withColumn("Net_Income"  ,company_df("Net_Income").cast(DoubleType())) \
                    .withColumn("Enterprise_Value"  ,company_df("Enterprise_Value").cast(DoubleType())) \
```

I  am getting error as  :

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cast'
```

Comment: I would expect `company_df("Revenue")` to throw a callable error, however did you also try `company_df["Revenue"].cast(DoubleType())` inside the withColumn?

Answer (score 3):

A short, clean, scalable solution
Change some columns, leave the rest untouched

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# That's not part of the solution, just a creation of a sample dataframe
# df = spark.createDataFrame([(10, 1,2,3,4),(20, 5,6,7,8)],'Id int, Revenue int ,GROSS_PROFIT int ,Net_Income int ,Enterprise_Value int')

cols_to_cast = ["Revenue" ,"GROSS_PROFIT" ,"Net_Income" ,"Enterprise_Value"]
df = df.select([F.col(c).cast('double') if c in cols_to_cast else c for c in df.columns])

df.printSchema()
```

---

```
root
 |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Revenue: double (nullable = true)
 |-- GROSS_PROFIT: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Net_Income: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Enterprise_Value: double (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If this helps

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 0),
(2, 1),
(3  ,1),
(4, 1),
(5, 0),
(6  ,0),
(7, 1),
(8  ,1),
(9  ,1),
(10,    1),
(11,    0),
(12,    0)],
('Time' ,'Tag1'))

df = df.withColumn('a', col('Time').cast('integer')).withColumn('a1', col('Tag1').cast('double'))
df.printSchema()
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, to @wwnde's answer you could do something as below -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

company_df = (company_df.withColumn("Revenue_cast" ,         col("Revenue_cast").cast(DoubleType()))  
                        .withColumn("GROSS_PROFIT_cast",     col("GROSS_PROFIT").cast(DoubleType()))    
                        .withColumn("Net_Income_cast"  ,     col("Net_Income").cast(DoubleType())) 
                        .withColumn("Enterprise_Value_cast", col("Enterprise_Value").cast(DoubleType()))
              )
```

Or,

```
company_df = (company_df.withColumn("Revenue_cast" ,        company_df["Revenue"].cast(DoubleType()))  
                      .withColumn("GROSS_PROFIT_cast",      company_df["GROSS_PROFIT".cast(DoubleType()))    
                      .withColumn("Net_Income_cast"  ,      company_df["Net_Income".cast(DoubleType())) 
                      .withColumn("Enterprise_Value_cast",  company_df["Enterprise_Value"].cast(DoubleType()))
             )
```